# Getting a summary of failed Test::More tests

Tags: perl, unit-testing

The project I'm working on (Perl) has a truly immense unit test suite. Depending on what code I'm working with, the number of tests run can easily hit tens of thousands.

When the `prove` command runs to completion, it indicates by number which tests failed. This gives me enough information to scroll back and figure out which tests failed and why, but it can be a nuisance.

Is there a way to get `prove` to provide a more thorough end-of-test summary of what failed? I'd at least like to know the names (and preferably packages) of the failed tests, but showing the failure messages would be welcome too.

Also, when you provide `prove` with a huge list of tests via the `--tests` parameter (which one of our tools does), is there a way for `prove` to provide an ongoing "Completed X out of Y tests" status update?

Comment: Could [`App::Prove::Plugin::Count`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Prove::Plugin::Count) be of interest?

Comment: Possibly. Enough to warrant a closer look, at the very least.

Comment: Just to clarify for myself -- do you mean that you'd like more detail in that final "Test Summary Report" (or so) ?  (After "completion" the tool shows details -- but you do also mention "end-of-test" summary)

Comment: If no existing tool meets your needs, note that TAP output is comparatively easy to parse so you would be able to build your own reporting tools.

Comment: @zdim, yup, ideally that's where I'd like to see the information.

Comment: I would like to see in the question an example of your test suite code, and maybe an example of the summary output you mention.